# forecolor is not working on selected text

Tags: .net, telerik

I am working in .net
i am using telerik editor
in this editor when i write some text and select particular text then change forecolor not change in design
so tell me what is problem

Answer (score 0):

See if the same problem happens with the editor demos online at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx. If it does - open a support issue with Telerik. If there is no problem in the online demos, the problem might be fixed already and you will need to upgrade your project with a more recent build of the RadEditor.